# Как сделать нестандартную колоночную верстку c Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Имеется форма, сверстанная с использованием Bootstrap. Согласно макету заказчика - необходимо выделить левую "колонку" более темным цветом + добавить на ее правой стороне утолщение по размеру соответствующего блока/блоков из правой колонки. Имеется ли возможность сделать это удобным и автоматизированным способом? Заранее спасибо.
[image: было]
 [image: надо]

Comment: приложите код вашей верстки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша верстка в упрощенном виде выглядит так:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <textarea class="form-control js-ckeditor"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

`.form-group` - играют роль строк, `label` располагается в колонке `col-sm-3` слева (у вас может быть другая колонка, и, следовательно, другая ширина).

Решить вашу задачу в рамках подобной верстки - можно в два этапа:

### Этап 1. Заливаем цветом левую половину формы

У нас нет явно заданной в верстке одной общей левой колонки для всего контента. Однако нам известен класс, который мы используем для лейблов (`col-sm-3`), а значит - известна ширина (в стилях бутстрапа, у `col-sm-3` - ширина 25%).

Это значит, что мы можем залить сплошным цветом - псевдоэлемент у формы, и расположить его ровно под левой колонкой, по ее размерам:

```
.form-horizontal::before {
  background-color: #fb1;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
```

И за счет `margin` вы можете подрегулировать расположение псевдоблока с учетом бутстраповского `$grid-gutter-width` - зазора между колонками.

### Этап 2. Ставим вертикальные черты по высоте инпутов

Решается точно так же - псевдоэлементами:

```
.form-horizontal .form-control::before {
  background-color: #bada55;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3px;
}
```

Таким способом вы располагаем псевдоэлемент чуть левее (`left: -50px;`) инпута. Значение подбираем специально, чтобы псевдоэлемент лег на границе залитого цветом блока из первого этапа.

---

Также обратите внимание, что на экранах меньших, чем указано у вас в колонках - форма будет не горизонтальная, а вертикальная, и заливать там левую половину не нужно, как и располагать вертикальные черты. Для этого - оберните ваши стили в `@media`.

Например у нас указано `col-sm-xxx`, значит наши стили нам нужны только на экранах от `$screen-sm-min` и выше. `@media`-запрос будет такой:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Виталий, за столь информативный и реально действующий ответ.