# Выравнивание элемента по цетнтру и по правому краю

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Благодаря замечательной подсказке Виталия ([Как сделать нестандартную колоночную верстку c Bootstrap?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568918/220785)) почти удалось сделать оформление, как на макете заказчика, но осталось выровнять заголовки (Tekst betaalpagina) по центру и левому краю относительно инпута.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать простым способом для всей формы( которая сделана с переключением по табам) 
Спасибо[image: это что есть]
[image: что требуется]

Comment: было бы хорошо посмотреть на html и css этих элементов. Но в общем, попробуйте поиграть с отступами padding и margin. Если стрелки синим указывают на `<label>` то их лучше делать `display:block;`

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался!!!

```
.label_parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.label_parent label{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```